# Java KeyEvent.getKeyCode() return a virtual key or ASCII?

Tags: java, input, keyboard, ascii

I want to create an array of all keys on the keyboard.

How many KeyCode are they ?
KeyEvent.getKeyCode() return ASCII or Virtual Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):

> The key being pressed or released is indicated by the `getKeyCode` and `getExtendedKeyCode` methods, which return a virtual key code.

You can count the number of keycodes yourself from the doc of [java.lang.Enum.KeyCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html):

If you're doing this in order to detect the keyboard layout, forget the Keycodes. Instead do:

```
InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();  
System.out.println(context.getLocale().toString());
```